# php - Insert data into MSSQL

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert data from php into MSSQL DB.
I'm able to do this:

```
sqlsrv_query($conn,"insert into <DB_Name> (First_Name,Last_Name) VALUES ('Dani','Yorgen')");
```

The thing is that i have an array which i want to use it instead of using static values.
i found this command:

```
$columns = implode(", ", array_values($headers));
```

this works perfeclty for me!

however when itry to do the same for the data it doesnt come as i want.
the result comes like this:
First_Name,Last_Name
when i need it to look like this:
'First_Name','Last_Name'

any ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: No.... just no. Use the `...VALUES (?, ?)"; $params = array('Dani', 'Yorgen'); $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);` syntax!

Comment: you didnt understand what i was reffering to, entering the data manually is not an option since the data is random.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to find the solution after bashing my head a little bit longer :)
it should go like this:

```
$columns = "'" . implode(",", array_values($headers)) . "'";
```

hope it will help those who needs.

Comment: No.... just no. Use the `...VALUES (?, ?)"; $params = array('Dani', 'Yorgen'); $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);` syntax!

Comment: you didnt understand what i was reffering to, entering the data manually is not an option since the data is random.

Comment: Well, you wrote in your question of data. When it comes to attribute names: `$columns = "'" . implode("', '", array_values($headers)) . "'";` Note the additional single quotation marks next to the comma.

Comment: The "however when itry to do the same for the data" statement totally threw me. Next time, please phrase it better.

Comment: @qräbnö - yeah sorry about that.